# How to Unit Test 'mkdir' function without file system access?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I use py.test for unit testing. I have something just like this:

```
Class Site(object):

    def set_path(self):
        """Checks if the blog folder exists. Creates new folder if necessary."""        
        if not os.path.isdir(self.user_dir):
            print "Creating new directory:", self.user_dir
            os.mkdir(self.user_dir)
        else:
            print "\n**", self.user, "directory already exists."
```

**How can I unit test this without touching the file system?**

Is there a general rule of thumb when dealing with such problems?

I've thought about it for a long time, and I cannot think of a solution.

My application will contain many file system accesses, and I don't know how to incorporate those methods when unit testing.

I want to specifically test that a folder is created in the correct path. The path is `self.user_dir`.

I also have a download function, that downloads an image into `self.user_dir`. I want to test that the image is downloaded. How would one go about testing this?

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: you can mock everything http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Matt Windows and Debian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two approaches you could use, mocking (preferred) or isolation:

**Mocking:**

At test time, replace os.mkdir with a "mock" version:

```
class MockMkdir(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.received_args = None
    def __call__(*args):
        self.received_args = args

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp():
        self._orig_mkdir = os.mkdir
        os.mkdir = MockMkdir()
    def tearDown():
        os.mkdir = self._orig_mkdir
    def test_set_path(self):
        site = Site()
        site.set_path('foo/bar')
        self.assertEqual(os.mkdir.received_args[0], 'foo/bar')
```

[Mock](http://mock.readthedocs.org/) is a library that helps you do this kind of thing more elegantly and with fewer lines of code.

**Isolation**

Use [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) to run your unittests within an isolated filesystem. After running each test case, revert the filesystem to a clean state. This is something of a sledgehammer approach but for testing very complicated libraries it might be easier to get this approach to work.